# "Permission Denied" on Mac while running Flowise locally

Tags: chatbot, flowise

I installed Flowise by following the Quick Start on Github:

```
npm install -g flowise
```

Then I used this command to start the local server:

```
npx flowise start
```

But ran into this error:

> sh: /opt/homebrew/bin/flowise: Permission denied

Can anyone help me how can i solve this issue?